# htaccess don't use index.html to send everything else to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I had a site completely run in wordpress. Made a new site from scratch and saved it to index.html. I made the htaccess file work for sending all other urls to the wordpress. The only problem is that I want the home page to be url.com/ instead of url.com/index.html in the address bar of the browser.

How do i keep everything working, except this one little thing?

```
# BEGIN WP Rocket v3.1.4
# Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
# Force UTF-8 for a number of file formats
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddCharset UTF-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .xml
</IfModule>

# FileETag None is not enough for every server.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

# Since we’re sending far-future expires, we don’t need ETags for static content.
# developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags
FileETag None

<IfModule mod_alias.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Powered-By "WP Rocket/3.1.4"
Header unset Pragma
Header append Cache-Control "public"
Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|js|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset Pragma
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Expires headers (for better cache control)
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on

# Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 1 month"

# cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest       "access plus 0 seconds"

# Your document html
ExpiresByType text/html                 "access plus 0 seconds"

# Data
ExpiresByType text/xml                  "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xml           "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/json          "access plus 0 seconds"

# Feed
ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType application/atom+xml      "access plus 1 hour"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed)
ExpiresByType image/x-icon              "access plus 1 week"

# Media: images, video, audio
ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"

# HTC files  (css3pie)
ExpiresByType text/x-component          "access plus 1 month"

# Webfonts
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf    "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff2  "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

# Gzip compression
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Active compression
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Force deflate for mangled headers
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
# Don’t compress images and other uncompressible content
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|rar|zip|exe|flv|mov|wma|mp3|avi|swf|mp?g|mp4|webm|webp|pdf)$ no-gzip dont-vary
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                  application/javascript \
                                  application/json \
                                  application/rss+xml \
                                  application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                  application/x-font-ttf \
                                  application/xhtml+xml \
                                  application/xml \
                                  font/opentype \
                                  image/svg+xml \
                                  image/x-icon \
                                  text/css \
                                  text/html \
                                  text/plain \
                                  text/x-component \
                                  text/xml
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType text/html .html_gzip
AddEncoding gzip .html_gzip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.html_gzip$ no-gzip
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteRule .* - [E=WPR_SSL:-https]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteRule .* - [E=WPR_ENC:_gzip]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !(wordpress_logged_in_|wp-postpass_|wptouch_switch_toggle|comment_author_|comment_author_email_) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/(.+/)?feed/?|/checkout/(.*)|/cart/|/my-account/(.*)|/wc-api/v(.*)|/(index\.php/)?wp\-json(/.*|$))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(facebookexternalhit).* [NC]
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/index%{ENV:WPR_SSL}.html%{ENV:WPR_ENC}" -f
RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/index%{ENV:WPR_SSL}.html%{ENV:WPR_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END WP Rocket

# BEGIN All In One WP Security
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files .htaccess>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
ServerSignature Off
LimitRequestBody 10240000
<Files wp-config.php>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_PINGBACK_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files xmlrpc.php>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_PINGBACK_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_DEBUG_LOG_BLOCK_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files debug.log>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_DEBUG_LOG_BLOCK_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_BLOCK_SPAMBOTS_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-comments-post\.php(.*)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://url\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1 [L]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_BLOCK_SPAMBOTS_END
# END All In One WP Security
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?$ http://url.com/index.html
</IfModule>


# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the following at the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

This instructs Apache to serve `index.html` when requesting the root directory, instead of `index.php` (ie. WordPress). The WordPress homepage will then no longer be accessible, unless you explicitly call `index.php`.

> currently, it forwards them to index.html instead of leaving the address the same url.com . leaving the url.com alone is the preferred action.

In addition to the above, you need to remove the last rule in your config file:

> ```
> RedirectMatch 301 ^/?$ http://url.com/index.html
> ```

And make sure you've cleared your browser cache since the 301 (permanent) redirect to `index.html` will have been cached.

Comment: sorry. this doesn't solve it. Maybe you didn't understand my question? the home page is now located at url.com/index.html and the blog is located at url.com/blog/index.php when someone goes to url.com currently, it forwards them to index.html instead of leaving the address the same url.com . leaving the url.com alone is the preferred action.

Comment: @ScotNery Hhhmmm, I thought I did (and do)... I'm not sure what else you are asking then? Setting `DirectoryIndex index.html` allows you to request `example.com/` instead of explicitly requesting `example.com/index.html`. (You do have to actually change the URLs you are linking to in your application. Do you need a redirect for SEO purposes?) "and the blog is located at url.com/blog/index.php" - you made no mention of this in your question? The WP front-controller in the code you posted is still pointing to `/index.php`?

Comment: @ScotNery "currently, it forwards them to index.html" - Ah, you need to remove the last rule: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/?$ http://url.com/index.html` - I've updated my answer.